# Sum Object property accoring to another property in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object similar to this:

```
[
  {
    origin: "XX",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
  },
  {
    origin: "ZZ",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
  }
]
```

I want to make the map and reduce these object in a way to get the sum of volumes for a certain property, in my case destination.

So I want to get something like:

```
 [
   {
     destination: "YY",
     volume: 1000
   }
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group/sum property values inside an array of objects(json) using Angular 4 Pipes or Rxjs operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500921/group-sum-property-values-inside-an-array-of-objectsjson-using-angular-4-pipes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to group the array by the `destination` property.  Here's a general `groupBy` function in TypeScript which creates a `Map` (ES2015 or greater, polyfill if you need it or replace with a plain object if you know the value will always be a string property) from `destination` values to the array of objects with that value for `destination`:

```
function groupBy<T, K extends keyof T>(key: K, arr: T[]): Map<T[K], T[]> {
  const map = new Map<T[K], T[]>();
  arr.forEach(t => {
    if (!map.has(t[key])) {
      map.set(t[key], []);
    }
    map.get(t[key])!.push(t);
  })
  return map;
}
```

Then, given your input,

```
const input = [
  {
    origin: "XX",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
  },
  {
    origin: "ZZ",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
  }
]
```

you can map the array of entries of the grouped `Map` to an array of objects containing the group `destination` and the sum of `volume` for each group:

```
const output = Array.from(groupBy("destination", input).entries())
  .map(([dest, objs]) => ({
    destination: dest,
    volume: objs.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.volume, 0)
  }))

console.log(JSON.stringify(output)); // produces the desired output
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

It works for me [in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=function%20groupBy%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%28key%3A%20K%2C%20arr%3A%20T%5B%5D%29%3A%20Map%3CT%5BK%5D%2C%20T%5B%5D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3CT%5BK%5D%2C%20T%5B%5D%3E%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20arr.forEach%28t%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28%21map.has%28t%5Bkey%5D%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20map.set%28t%5Bkey%5D%2C%20%5B%5D%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20map.get%28t%5Bkey%5D%29%21.push%28t%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%29%0D%0A%20%20return%20map%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20origin%3A%20%22XX%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20destination%3A%20%22YY%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20volume%3A%20500%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20origin%3A%20%22ZZ%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20destination%3A%20%22YY%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20volume%3A%20500%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20output%20%3D%20Array.from%28groupBy%28%22destination%22%2C%20input%29.entries%28%29%29%0D%0A%20%20.map%28%28%5Bdest%2C%20objs%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20destination%3A%20dest%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20volume%3A%20objs.reduce%28%28acc%2C%20cur%29%20%3D%3E%20acc%20%2B%20cur.volume%2C%200%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%29%29%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log%28JSON.stringify%28output%29%29%3B) which is using v2.5.1 as of today.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the code doesn't compile in typescript knowing that I have the version 2.5.3 do I need to download the types definitions ? to extend the .from() and name Map ?

Comment: Added a link to the TypeScript Playground above to demonstrate that it does compile in TypeScript without an issue.  What exactly do you mean when you say the code doesn't compile?  What error do you get?  Or does it compile but not run in your browser?

Comment: Ah, sorry, as I mentioned above the code requires ES2015 or greater.  In your [`tsconfig`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), make sure you include `"ES2015"` in `lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```js
var array = [{
    origin: "XX",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
  },
  {
    origin: "ZZ",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
  }
];

function sumFn(a, propType, propVal) {
  var i = 0;
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    if (a[propType] && a[propType] === propVal) {
      i += a.volume;
    }
  });
  console.log({
    [propType]: propVal,
    volume: i
  });
}

sumFn(array, "destination", "YY");
```

Answer (score 0):

If one uses the power of `Array.reduce` one even can provide a generic base collector method that is agnostic of any data structure, but uses it's first `collector` or `accumulator` argument for carrying data structure specific getter/setter functionality in oder to operate this specific data.

An implementation that properly operates the OP's given example code then might look similar to the following one ...

```js
var dataList = [{

    origin: "XX",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
}, {
    origin: "ZZ",
    destination: "YY",
    volume: 500
}, {
    origin: "XX",
    destination: "AA",
    volume: 200
}, {
    origin: "ZZ",
    destination: "AA",
    volume: 100
}];

function collectSourceValueConnectedTargetSummaries(collector, dataItem) {  // a generic data structure agnostic summary approach ...
    var registry    = collector.registry;
    var sourceValue = collector.getSourceValue(dataItem);
    var summaryItem = registry[sourceValue];

    if (!summaryItem) {
        summaryItem = registry[sourceValue] = Object.assign({}, collector.summaryItem);

        collector.putSummarySource(summaryItem, sourceValue);
        collector.summaryList.push(summaryItem);
    }
    collector.summarizeTarget(summaryItem, collector.getTargetValue(dataItem));

    return collector;
}

var result = dataList.reduce(collectSourceValueConnectedTargetSummaries, {  // ... that makes use of data structure specific methods.

    registry: {},

    // this two methods just read data and their's implementation reflects the data structure that gets operated.
    getSourceValue:     function (dataItem) { return dataItem.destination },
    getTargetValue:     function (dataItem) { return dataItem.volume },

    // the next two methods do control the mapping process (the output) of all summary data.
    putSummarySource:   function (summaryItem, value) { summaryItem.destination = value; },
    summarizeTarget:    function (summaryItem, value) { summaryItem.volume = (summaryItem.volume + value); },

    summaryItem:  { /*destination: '', */volume: 0 },
    summaryList: []

}).summaryList;

console.log('dataList : ', dataList);
console.log('reduced dataList / result : ', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```